# Hive table becomes unavailable during spark SaveAsTable in partitionOverwrite mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My java spark job writes into four tables using spark `saveAsTable` in partition Overwrite mode. While write is happening in hive, it becomes unavailable for any form of read, and we get `Table or View not found` exception. At a time, write happens to only one partition (which is essentially a new partition). Can we help this situation by allowing reads for (older) partitions which are not in progress/update?

I am using parquet format to persist files.